# Reading .gz file line by line

Tags: php

I am trying to read large .gz file line by line.
Here is what i got so far:

```
$sfp = gzopen($filename, "rb");
while (!gzeof($sfp)) 
{
    $line = gzread($sfp, 4096);
}
```

and thats where the problem comes in, gzread reading the length specified in variable (in this case 4096) and ignoring new lines .

I checked "fget" function and it works properly, so its reading line limiting the size by hitting new line or the size which ever comes first.
How I can do the same with gzread or any work around ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `fgets()` just like reading an ordinary file.

You shouldn't use `b` mode if you're reading lines, since line-by-line implies it's a text file.

```
$sfp = gzopen($filename, "r");
while ($line = fgets($sfp)) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: but this way its trying to get whole file in memory, which creates error when file really big. The whole point is to read large file line by line

Comment: Why do you think it reads the whole file? `fgets()` just reads one line.

Comment: You can also use `gzgets()`. I'm not sure why one would be preferred over the other, I use `fgets()` in my applications that read gzip files.