# gzXXX() versus fXXX() functions after gzopen()

Tags: php, gzip

I have applications that open and process gzip files like this:

```
$fh = gzopen($fn, "r");
if ($fh) {
    while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and it works fine, using `fgets()` with a gzip filehandle. Today, while answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653497/reading-gz-file-line-by-line) I noticed that there are also `gz` versions of all the file-reading and -writing functions, so this could have been written as

```
$fh = gzopen($fn, "r");
if ($fh) {
    while ($line = gzgets($fh)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, I just tried the following and it worked:

```
$fh = fopen(".bashrc", "r");
$line = gzgets($fh);
echo $line;
```

So is there really any significant difference between the `gzXXX()` and `fXXX()` functions that read and write, or are they just synonyms and the difference is determined by how the file is opened (and to confuse things further, `gzopen()` will also open non-gzip files, and then read without decompression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on the source, `gzopen()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b5c7a83dcab670a5ac6070ac3774a5d221fd5ecc/ext/zlib/zlib.c#L669) uses [`php_stream_gzopen()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d1764ca33018f1f2e4a05926c879c67ad4aa8da5/ext/zlib/zlib_fopen_wrapper.c#L106-L107) to return a wrapped stream, which is why the `f...` family of functions works fine on the resource. (This is similar to how stream wrappers allow you to open filelike objects with e.g. `http://`, and so on.)

As for why you can `fopen()` and then `gzgets()`, [your hunch is correct](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d1764ca33018f1f2e4a05926c879c67ad4aa8da5/ext/zlib/zlib.c#L1252-L1257); `gzclose`, `gzeof`, `gzgetc`, `gzgets`, `gzpassthru`, `gzputs`, `gzread`, `gzrewind`, `gzseek`, `gztell`, and `gzwrite` are all aliases for the same `f...` functions.